# Lines and planes at space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

First of all, sorry for my poor English.

Can someone please help me?

How can I find the parametric equation of the line that have $ A=(1, -2, -1) $ and passes through the skew lines

$r:$

$ x= z -1$

$ y= 2z - 3 $

$s:$

$x= z-2$

$y= -z + 1$

Thanks!

Comment: The word you want for two non-parallel, non-intersecting lines in three or more dimensions is "skew".

Comment: hahahah thanks!

Comment: Apparently from a word in Middle English meaning "to move obliquely"; the surviving word in modern English is "askew", meaning crooked or out of alignment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equations for a line passing through $ \ (1, -2, -1) \ $ are $ \ x = 1 + at \ , \ y = -2 + bt \ , \ z = -1 + ct \ . $  This will hold true at the points where this line meets lines $ \ r \ $ and $ \ s \ $ (*assuming* it **does** intersect them both -- I presumed that the problem is constructed so that this happens, though it shouldn't be expected to do so in general).

Looking at line $ \ r \ $ , the intersection is at some value of the parameter $ \ r \ $ such that

$$ \begin{array}{cc}1 + ar \ = \ (-1 + cr) -1 \\-2 + br \ = \ 2 \cdot (-1 + cr) -3\end{array} \ \Rightarrow \ \begin{array}{cc}ar \ = \ cr -3 \\ br \ = \  2cr -3\end{array} \ .$$

Doing the same for line $ \ s \ $ produces

$$ \begin{array}{cc}1 + as \ = \ (-1 + cs) -2 \\-2 + bs \ = \ -(-1 + cs) + 1\end{array} \ \Rightarrow \ \begin{array}{cc}as \ = \ cs -4 \\ bs \ = \  -cs +4\end{array} \ , $$

from which we see that  $ \ a = -b \ $ , since $ \ s \neq 0 \ . $  Inserting this result back into the first pair of equations yields

$$ \begin{array}{cc}ar \ = \ cr -3 \\ -ar \ = \  2cr -3\end{array} \ \Rightarrow \ 3cr = 6 \ \Rightarrow \ c \ = \frac{2}{r} \ . $$

From this, we find  $ \ ar \ = \ 2 - 3 \ = \ -1 \ $ and $ \ br \ = \ 4 - 3 \ = \ 1 \ . $  We now have the relation among the coefficients

$$ r \ = \ \frac{-1}{a} \ = \ \frac{1}{b} \ = \ \frac{2}{c} \ \Rightarrow \ 2a \ =  -2b \ =  -c . $$

We cannot pin down specific numerical values for these coefficients, but it is not actually necessary, since any non-zero scalar multiplication of values for them is equivalent to a non-zero scalar multiplication of the parameter $ \ t \ $ .  Another way of saying this is that a direction vector for the line in question is $ \langle 1, -1, -2 \rangle \ . $

**ADDENDUM:**  If we use the scaling for $ \ a = 1 \ $ (and thus $ \ b = -1 \ , \ c = -2 \ $ ), we can quickly determine that $ \ r = -1 \ $ , with the intersection point on that line being $ \ (0, -1, 1 ) \ , $ and that $ \ s = -\frac{4}{3} \ $ , with that intersection point located at $ \ ( -\frac{1}{3} , -\frac{2}{3} , \frac{5}{3} ) \ . $  These results are compatible with the relations given for lines $ \ r \ $ and $ \ s \ . $

Comment: Wow, you are so smart! thanks a lot!

Comment: Just lucky -- the problem could have had _no_ solution.  (Actually, if the two sets of equations turned out to be incompatible, that would tell us that there is _no_ line that passes through the given point and _both_ of the skew lines...)

Comment: I don't believe in luck ;)